# Internet Explorer automation not working with IE11

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I have some code that retrieves data from multiple websites via Internet Explorer automation in VBA. My code worked without problems with IE8, but in IE11, after the Navigate method of the Internet Explorer object is called, the Document and LocationURL are not updated; they still refer to the previously displayed website. Here's some code to reproduce the problem:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "start"
    Dim ie
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic"
    wait ie
    Debug.Print "Current URL: " & ie.LocationURL
    ie.Navigate "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office"
    wait ie
    Debug.Print "Current URL: " & ie.LocationURL
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Wait(ie As Variant)
    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
End Sub
```

When a run the above Test sub on a machine with IE8, it prints two different URLs, which is the expected behavior. However, when I run the same code on a machine with IE11, it prints the first URL twice. Any idea what might be wrong?

**Update**: I couldn't find a solution, so I went for the workaround of opening a new IE window for each URL.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the VBA IE automation that you are using, however it sounds like you are hitting the same issue as Selenium WebDriver on IE11.

You may need to follow the same steps provided by the in the Selenium Wiki.

> For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target
>   computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
>   of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the
>   key you must examine in the registry editor is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
>   installations, the key is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
>   FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
>   created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
>   DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Hopefully that fixes your problem!

Comment: I tried adding both registry keys and rebooted the machine, but unfortunately it didn't work... Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Worked for me - on IE11 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

THX, You helped me.
W7 Ultimate 64bit czech, IE11, VBA in Microstation V8i
I use code like:

```
Public explorer As Object
....
Set explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
....

If InStr(explorer.LocationURL, "CAPTCHA") = 0 Then
...
End If
```