# Use VBA to Click on javascript href link

Tags: javascript, excel, href, vba

I am trying to automate a program that looks up the property tax returns for specific parcels of land. The website I am using to do so is [here](http://fiscalofficer.cuyahogacounty.us/AuditorApps/real-property/REPI/default.asp).

In this example, the parcel ID that I am looking up is 648-30-013.

When I search for that parcel, I arrive at a page with a link that I need to click. The html for the link is below:

```
<a href='javascript:SubmitThisForm("General.asp", "64830013");'>648-30-013</a>
```

I've tried using the following code to click the link, but have not been successful. The section I am having trouble with is the last section 'click on parcel ID link. The code works fine when stepped through, but when execucted the objCollection variable does not populate.

```
'Declare Variables

' Counter variable
Dim i As Integer

' Internet explorer variables
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim lookupURL As String

' Excel variables
Dim currentParcel As String
Dim year As Integer
Dim jobs As String
Dim completedLoops
Dim totalLoops

' Input variables
'These are the counter variables that loop through your lookup data; where to start and end and how long to loop for
completedLoops = 0
totalLoops = 1
lookupURL = "http://fiscalofficer.cuyahogacounty.us/AuditorApps/real-property/REPI/default.asp"


'Set value of current lookup based on a starting value and # of loops completed
currentParcel = "648-30-013"
Application.StatusBar = "Executing " & completedLoops & " of " & totalLoops & " loops"


' Establish Internet Exploere Instance
' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

' Navigate to website
IE.Navigate lookupURL

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

' Click on 'By Parcel #' tab
' Create a list of all the <div> tags on the page
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

' Loop through all <div> tags to find the one with the correct name and input current search term into tag
i = 0
Do While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).ID = "tabTabdhtmlgoodies_tabView2_1" Then
        Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        objElement.Click
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop


' Input parcel ID
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
i = 0
Do While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "parcelNum" Then
        objCollection(i).Value = currentParcel
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

' Click on search button
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
i = 0
Do While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "b_2" Then
        Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        objElement.Click
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)


' Click on parcel ID link
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Debug.Print objCollection.Length
i = 0
Do While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).innerText = currentParcel Then
        Debug.Print objCollection(i).innerText
        Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        objElement.Click
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Please let me know if there are better ways to click on this link.

Comment: Exactly what happens when you run your code?  Have you tried debugging to find out whether you're getting the elements you expect?  For example try adding `Debug.Print objCollection(i).innerText` inside your loop and check the output.

Comment: Hi Tim - thanks for responding with the tip. The code works fine when I step through line by line and the link is clicked, but when I execute the code from start to end it doesn't populate any values into the objCollection variable (length = 0). Do you have any tips?

Comment: If it works when stepping though but not otherwise, then it's possible the page needs some time to complete and you're not allowing for that.  The typical tests (e.g. for ReadyState and Busy) do not take into account "dynamic" ("AJAX") pages where further content is loaded once the page is ready.  That type of page is pretty common now so when you see this issue that's pretty likely the cause.  Try adding a wait before trying to access the elements.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I tried adding a wait and it still doesn't seem to populate the variable. I've updated the code snippet in the question above to include a it more - would you mind taking a look at the final part to see if you have any suggestions for what else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

If you're doing any amount of web scraping then it's much cleaner to abstract as much of the "guts" as you can into utility methods which you can re-use and which help de-clutter your main code, so you can more easily focus on the "what" versus the "how".

```
Sub TT()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim lookupURL As String, div As Object, el As Object
    Dim currentParcel As String
    Dim year As Integer
    Dim jobs As String
    Dim completedLoops
    Dim totalLoops


    completedLoops = 0
    totalLoops = 1
    lookupURL = "http://fiscalofficer.cuyahogacounty.us/AuditorApps/real-property/REPI/default.asp"

    currentParcel = "648-30-013"

    Application.StatusBar = "Executing " & completedLoops & " of " & totalLoops & " loops"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate lookupURL ' Navigate to website
    WaitFor IE

    Set div = IE.document.getelementById("tabTabdhtmlgoodies_tabView2_1")

    If Not div Is Nothing Then

        div.Click
        WaitFor IE
        ' Input parcel ID
        If PopulateInputByName(IE, "parcelNum", currentParcel) Then

            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

            Set el = GetNamedInput(IE, "b_2")
            If Not el Is Nothing Then

                el.Click
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)

                Set el = GetLinkByText(IE, currentParcel)
                If Not el Is Nothing Then el.Click 'done!

            Else
                MsgBox "Input 'b_2' not found!"
            End If


        Else
            MsgBox "ParcelNum input not found!"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "Tab div not found!"
    End If

End Sub

'*** Begin utility functions ***
'utility: wait until page has loaded
Sub WaitFor(IE As Object)
    Do While IE.ReadyState < 4 Or IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub

'utility: find a named input and set its value: return True if this succeeded
Function PopulateInputByName(IE, theName, theValue) As Boolean
    Dim el As Object, rv As Boolean
    Set el = GetNamedInput(IE, theName)
    If Not el Is Nothing Then
        el.Value = theValue
        rv = True
    End If
    PopulateInputByName = rv
End Function

'utility: find a named input
Function GetNamedInput(IE, theName) As Object
    Dim objColl As Object, el As Object, rv As Object
    Set objColl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each el In objColl
        If el.Name = theName Then
            Set rv = el
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set GetNamedInput = rv
End Function

'utility: click link with specific text
Function GetLinkByText(IE, theText) As Object
    Dim objColl As Object, el As Object, rv As Object
    Set objColl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each el In objColl
        If el.innerText = theText Then
            Set rv = el
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set GetLinkByText = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim - this is great! Thank you so much for your help - your utility functions are a great resource for me to use. I still run into the same issue when executing vs. stepping-through your code however - the link with the parcel ID is clicked when stepping-through but not when executing. Is there perhaps a setting or something in VBA or Internet Explorer that I need to change to allow it to work during execution?

Comment: There is no functional difference I can think of between running your code straight through and using F8, apart from timing, so I would try increasing the "wait" time just before the problem step.

Comment: Hm that is so strange. Even when I increase the wait time to 30 seconds it still will not function properly when running the code straight through. Does it work for you when you execute through? I've done a bit of research to try to find answers, but haven't found anything. Best I can find is: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/956625-vba-to-ie-works-in-step-through-not-when-run.html but it seems like our code already accounts for that. Any other thoughts? I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: Yes, it works for me if I just let it run: IE10 Excel 2013.  I can't see any code in that question you link to.

Comment: I was able to find an answer here....that was pretty obscure! Thank you for your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488988/internet-explorer-automation-not-working-with-ie11 I am using IE11 so I guess that key must have been removed as part of the new program or something...